# Why isn't a reactive variable watchable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, reactive-programming, watch

I am developing a simple application in Vue3 and TypeScript. I defined an `interface` and initialized a reactive variable `scrap` that I the wanted to watch:

```
interface Scrap {
  Text: string,
  ModificationDate: string,
}
const scrap = ref<Scrap>({ Text: '', ModificationDate: '' } as Scrap)
watch(() => scrap, () => console.log('change'))
```

`scrap.Text` is modified in the application UI and I see these changes in DevTools → Vue.

The `watch()` callback is however not fired, despite that change. What is the reason for that?

I tried both `watch(scrap, () => console.log('change'))` and `watch(() => scrap, () => console.log('change'))` but there were no difference in behaviour (nor errors or warnings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the whole object is watched, it should be a deep watcher:

```
watch(scrap, () => console.log('change'), { deep: true })
```

Otherwise a specific property should be watched:

```
watch(() => scrap.value.Text, () => console.log('change'))
```