# What is the use of a shallow watch of an object?

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs3, watch

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72744325/why-isnt-a-reactive-variable-watchable), I learned that in order to `watch` a whole object, the `{deep: true}` option must be used.

I deduce from that requirement that there is a case where one would use a shallow `watch` on an object.

What are the typical cases for such a `watch`? What needs to change in order for the callback to be triggered?

Comment: For your specific case mentioned in another question, shallow watch would be applicable if there were a need to watch on ` scrap.value` ref reassignments. It's unknown if the use of `ref` was justified. If this were `reactive` object, top-level properties would be watched instead, like it was expected

Answer (score 1):

Deep watch is for tracking changes on an objects properties. Obviously it has a performance impact. Most of the time simple data types are watched instead of objects. So enabling it by default makes no sense.

So if you do not need to track changes of an objects properties you do not need to use deep watch.

Shallow use for an object is only makes sense if the object assignment changes totaly.

1. No need for deepWatch:

```js
const searchString=ref('');
watch(searchString, () => {
   //perform a search 
})
```

2. Deep watch is necessery to  detect changes:

```js
const filters=ref({name:'',price:'',country:''});
watch(filters, () => {
 //perform a filter operation depending on filter options
}, { deep: true });
```

In the second example you need to set `filters.value` to a new object each time is you do not use `deep`